# install hp officejet 5740 e-all-in-one ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, printing, hp

i am trying to install the hp officejet 5740 e-all-in-one on ubuntu 14.04. Using the lsusb i can see that the printer is connected to the USB:

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 03f0:cd11 Hewlett-Packard

and i can install the printer from the system setting, which however gives me Officejet j5700 Series, hpcups 3.14.3 as the printer make and model although i selected several times officejet j5740, which is the most similar name i get from the list. the defaults seems to be indeed the officejet 5600.

I can print the test page all right but then, when printing a file, the page is offset thus the printer is useless. this not to talk about the scanner and fax.

using the hplip -- which i have installed from the software centre and is marked 3.14.3 -- no printer is identified from any port, specifically on the USB. Before I was using the HP 2540 which was correctly detected and managed by hplip. I also tried to install the hplip 3.15.2 from terminal but my  superuser password is not recognized.

how can i properly install the 5740?

best regards

luigi

Answer (score 3):

You have to have the LATEST hplib installed, and you have to download the installer here:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_5740_series.html

Then follow the directions in the download link. As of 07/15/15 the latest is `hplip-3.15.7`.

Comment: To get hplip 3.14.10 or higher you can also install Ubuntu 15.04 (hplip 3.15.2) or higher.